# How can I get GeoServer WMS layer attributes in QGIS?

Tags: geoserver, wms, qgis-3, getfeatureinfo, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am trying to connect GeoServer wms layers in QGIS for the purpose of web mapping. The layers are shown properly in QGIS but the layers attribute that means layer information is not visible in layer properties.

Comment: A WMS (web map service) layer consists of raster images. It doesn't have features with attributes. If you want features with attributes, you need a WFS (web *feature* service) layer.

Comment: Or you can use the identify tool to see individual feature attributes

Answer (score 1):

WMS does not have attributes. In geoserver, wfs of the layer should be available too. Add wfs layer instead of wms.